# Start application as logged user from NSIS installer launched by system service

Tags: windows, service, installation, nsis

I work on an NSIS installer doing (among other things) in this order:

1. uses UAC to run elevated (this is needed for other things made by
   the installer)
2. closes explorer.exe
3. starts explorer.exe (using
   Exec command)
4. launches the installed executable, running as same
   user as the one launching (using Exec command)

and everything works good.

Now the installer is requested to be launched by a Service.
This ends in both explorer and the installed program been launched as SYSTEM.

How can modify the installer to get the program run as current logged user?

I know if it was not for steps 2-3 I could use explorer to launch my executable (this works!), but this does not fit my needs, since I need also to stop and start explorer.exe as the current user.

Any idea how can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are restarting Explorer because you are installing a shell extension then this is a flawed idea. A shell extension can be loaded in any process at any time (GetOpenFilename() etc). You should rename the file that is in use and delete it later with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE and/or MoveFileEx.

If you are restarting Explorer for some other reason (Why?) it is better to restart it with the token from OpenProcessToken (or WTSQueryUserToken if you could not get Explorers token)